# Multiple strings in 2d array assigning in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, file, assign

I am facing a problem while I am trying to assign multiple strings in a 2d array in `C`
While I am reading a file as you can see with name log, if i see the userid which is a string " " I keep the line in array users as a string with method `strcpy()` because this worked.Then if a condition happens I want this string to pass it to another array with name `denied_users` but I get the error here.I also tried `strcpy(denied_users[find_result-1],users[userslen])` but also didn't work.

```
char string[512], *access_denied, *userid;
access_denied = "Action denied flag: 1"; //key word that lookin for
userid = "User ID: ";
int line_num = 1;
int find_result = 0;

char users[1000][1000];
char denied_users[1000][1000];

int userslen = 0;
while (fgets(string, 512, log) != NULL) {
    if ((strstr(string, userid)) != NULL)
        strcpy(users[userslen], string);

    userslen++;
    if ((strstr(string, access_denied)) != NULL) {
        denied_users[find_result - 1] = users[userslen]; //how to //pass it here
        find_result++;
    }
    line_num++;
}
```

Comment: no because the string value is different there.

Comment: if i try a printf() inside and outside  if ((strstr(string, access_denied)) != NULL) this if to show the string value is different. At the first case string prints all the file, while on the second case prints the value =access_denied

Comment: what about strcpy(&denied_users[find_result][0],&users[userslen][0]); note that there is "find_result" but not "find_result - 1", since with it you go out of buffer at the first time

Comment: strcpy(&denied_users[find_result][0],&users[userslen][0]); 

I tried that but also when I try to printf the denied_users array it doesn't print anything without error.Same happens with strcpy(denied_users[find_result-1],users[userslen])

Comment: how do you print it?

Comment: `int j;
  for(j=0; j<find_result; j++){
   printf("%s",denied_users[j]);}`

Comment: I tried also in 2 nested loops and finally print something else compared to users array.Maybe it's wrong technique.

Comment: that's mostly correct, but i'd add "\n" to have each one on the separate line: "%s\n"